# Unity version control problems, does not let me to check in my changes

Tags: unity-game-engine, plasticscm

So I have a problem with my unity version control plasticSCM, I have changes to my prefabs however it does not want to push them to the main code, and it gives the error. If I will make changes to another element it works perfectly and pushes new updates.

["Error - Unity Version Control
There are no changes in the workspace / Users/xxx/Desktop/videoGaming" which is on the screenshot,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccOaW.png)

Any suggestion on what should I do?
Thanks

I tried to add to ignore and then back but nothing, shell it also nothing I need it. I also tried to do the undo but it was still the same, it did not even want to do the undo.

Comment: First suggestion is update the question to include your control code so someone can review it.  If the prefab changes are the focus, post that code.  Next update the error message to a text version, no one fixes questions with images and no code.